# Is a 555/6 suitable for generating a 1-3000Hz square wave from 0-5V control voltage

Tags: pic, 555, vco

The goal is to use a control voltage from 0-5V to generate a square wave signal from 1 (ideally, but around 10 would be acceptable) to 3000 Hz (linearly, although I could work around it not being linear).

I've been experimenting with a 555 (556 actually) and can easily achieve that by altering R1, R2 and C, but I need to keep those fixed, as the only variable input I'll have is the voltage.

Duty cycle is not particularly critical here although around 50:50 would be nice - it's to control a stepper motor driver which needs a minimum 1.5uS pulse, so only the most ridiculous duty cycle would not conform at those frequencies.

I've looked at the formula at [What is the equation for the 555 timer control voltage?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/101530/what-is-the-equation-for-the-555-timer-control-voltage) (the one at the top of tardate's answer; the one in the question appears to be wrong) and by applying it it appears clear that the range I want is not possible with just Vcontrol.

I'm open to using both timers in the 556 if that could work, but I haven't been able to figure out a solution.

If a 555 is just not appropriate for this, can someone suggest an alternative?  I could always dust off the PIC programmer and get it to do this but I was hoping there was a simpler alternative.

Comment: Seems that your goal is to design a VCO (Voltage controlled oscillator). Google "555 vco" or go for 566 IC.

Comment: Please provide a circuit diagram with the tool

Comment: 3.5 magnitudes is an awful lot of frequency range for a 555...

Comment: 3000:1 is pushing the limits of all commercial VCO's. with external current sources and negative bias you "may"  get 1000:1 here http://www.electroschematics.com/7170/wide-frequency-range-555-vco/

Comment: why not use a PLL with a 1 decade linear VCO and decade counters?

Comment: for a free software signal generator , I use Audacity, do any range from mHz to >> 20kHz

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 - I've used Audacity, although generating that range on a PC is easy anyway. The issue is getting it to the stepper driver. I have a K8055 but it is hard limited by needing 20ms per command, so 40ms per pulse, which is way too slow. I'm sure there's other hardware I could use but I'm trying to be creative with what I have so planned to use the DAC to generate 0-5V instead. Using a VCO seems an option; I see they mostly generate much higher frequencies but I can always count/divide.  Otherwise the MCU route is starting to look like a more viable option.

Comment: Dust off the PIC. It *is* your "simpler alternative".

Comment: @RohatKılıç - thanks - that appears to be exactly what I am trying to do (so simple when you know how...).  I googled what you suggested and http://learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Voltage-controlled-oscillator-VCO-circuit-with-a-555-timer.php seems pretty spot on - I'll try to take it from there.  BTW I googled a bucket load of stuff before that on 555s, but knowing to add "VCO" was what I was missing.

Comment: Honestly, if it's for controlling a stepper, I wouldn't go for a VCO. You'd rather use any decent MCU with a PWM output (and eventually an ADC, if you really want to keep the analog input control). Design will be much simpler, and you'll achieve a much wider frequency range.

Comment: Doing a Google search, I found several designs for a 555 VCO right off the bat: [First One](http://learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Voltage-controlled-oscillator-VCO-circuit-with-a-555-timer.php "First One") - [Second One](http://www.electroschematics.com/7170/wide-frequency-range-555-vco/ "Second One") - [Third One](http://www.555-timer-circuits.com/555-vco.html "Third One"). Take a look at these, and do not be afraid to ask Google :)

Comment: Thanks, although 1 and 3 are simply using the Control pin as you'd expect on a 555, and do not get around the low frequency range that the formula I refer to implies.  2 is more interesting - I will look into that, although I notice the author says "I do not generally recommend this circuit".  As in my comment above I googled plenty, but wasn't aware of VCOs so didn't know to add the search term.

Comment: his 2nd is same as my link and if you use negative bias for current sink then it works better than their's

Comment: Simply providing links to circuits which will not meet the poster's needs is not being helpful. None of those circuits will provide the performance required. Apparently you did not attempt to understand the circuits which you recommended.

Answer (score 1):

It feels a little wrong to answer my own question, but just to conclude this, I think it's fair to conclude that a 555 is not really suitable for this specific task.  Thanks to those who commented.

I'm going to go the MCU route - it gives me more control and if I need to broaden the frequency range even further at some point it's then easy-enough to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the range from 1 to 3000 Hz it might be easier to use a counter as a frequency divider, for instance divide by 16 and let the 555 generate 16 to 48000 Hz. Dividing by a power of 2 provides a clean square wave with 50 % high and 50 % low.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the 555 as a comparator you can make a VCO that will handle that range by adding an op-amp and a transistor.

The op-amp acts as an integrator and the transistor, controlled by the 555 output, changes from positive to negative integration.