# What is equation for the 555 timer control voltage in monostable

Tags: pwm, 555, monostable

How do i get the 555 timer in monostable output frequency when there is voltage apply at control voltage. I only able to find the formula for astable which is [image]

Orignal post:-
[What is the equation for the 555 timer control voltage?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/101530/what-is-the-equation-for-the-555-timer-control-voltage)

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" actually mean?

Comment: the answer i got by using that formula when voltage is apply at CV the value is too far apart

Comment: you suck at explaining stuff too LOL.

Comment: uhmm basically i try to use the formula t=1.1* R*C when there no CV voltage apply i able to get the right answer for the output on time. But when there is voltage apply at CV when i try to use the formula t=1.1* R*C the answer is too far apart to consider acceptable sorry for the poor explaination